# Mormonism teaches that Jesus and Satan are spirit brothers and they both volunteered to be the Savior of mankind. Where in the Bible is this taught?

Tags: biblical-basis, lds

They base this teaching on Job 38:7, "When the morning stars sang together, And all the sons of God shouted for joy."

The LDS prove this plan based on their own writings, not from the Bible. They quote from the Book of Abraham at Abraham 3:27 and from the Book of Moses at Moses 4:2. This story is explained here from their own books/writings: [Jesus Christ, Our Chosen Leader and Savior](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-3-jesus-christ-our-chosen-leader-and-savior?lang=eng).

> Our Father said, “Whom shall I send?” Jesus Christ, who was called Jehovah, said, “Here am I, send me” (Abraham 3:27).

> Satan, who was called Lucifer, also came, saying, “Behold, here am I, send me, I will be thy son, and I will redeem all mankind, that one soul shall not be lost, and surely I will do it; wherefore give me thine honor” (Moses 4:1).

> Jesus said, “Father, thy will be done, and the glory be thine forever” (Moses 4:2).

So again, where in the Holy Bible is this plan explained?

Comment: Mr. Bond please be more specific about the term bible here. If you ask an Ids question, you have to accept their Scriptures. Questions to Catholics or Orthodox Churches and would have to accept their Duerterocanonical texts. **'Traditional Christianity struggled for many years to define its canon, to determine which of its writings were sacred, inspired, and authoritative. The Latter-day Saint concept of canon differs from that of other Christians. In addition to the Bible, the Latter-day Saint canon includes the Book of Mormon, the Doctrine and Covenants, and the Pearl of Great Price."**

Comment: Your question seems to assume that everything the LDS teaches must be found in a specific canon, you call “the Bible”. As there are many canons, that gives at least one problem, maybe two.

Is your assumption correct and does the LDS claim all they teach is based on a “the Bible”? And what canon makes that “the Bible” and is that the same canon as your “the Bible”?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150615/discussion-on-question-by-mr-bond-mormonism-teaches-that-jesus-and-satan-are-sp); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Mr. Bond and all others please go to chat.

Comment: Stay there. I do not to see the type of comments here that I am seeing. Everyone is to go there or I will delete comments.

Answer (score 6):

Having looked through quite a selection of official Latter Day Saint publications that I have collected over the years, I would venture to suggest (subject to LDS correction if I have misunderstood) that the following Bible texts are put together as support for the teaching that in his pre-mortal state, Jesus was an elder brother of another spirit called Lucifer (Satan).

**Colossians 1:15**, with **Romans 8:29** and **Hebrews 12:23** are used to show that Jesus is called "the firstborn of every creature, the firstborn among many brethren, and that there is the church of the firstborn in heaven, even as the Church on earth is also named after him." (As stated in their booklet, *What the Mormons Think of Christ*, p.25, published 1976)

The booklet interprets such verses as meaning that the firstborn spirit child of 'the Father' (in a spirit realm) was named Jehovah, who later came to Earth as the man, Jesus.It adds (on that same page)"

> "...all men lived in a premortal estate before they were born into
> this world; all were born in the premortal existence as the spirit
> children of the Father. Christ was the firstborn spirit child"
> (*Ibid.* p.25)

The important point with regard to this question is that **"Christ was the firstborn spirit child."** That means that "Father" God thereafter fathered more spirit children (and one of them was called Lucifer.) Then the LDS booklet *Plan of Salvation* (published 1978) uses **Job 38:2-4 & 7** to make the next step. **Luke 3:38**  is linked to **Ecclesiastes 12:7** to say that Jesus returned to Father God after he died (as do all humans who had also once been in heaven as pre-mortals, the booklet claims). Then **Hebrews 12:9**, which speaks of 'the Father of spirits', is invoked to conclude that pre-mortal Jesus, pre-mortal humans, and all spirit creatures in the Father's heaven were those "sons of God" in Job who "shouted for joy in "the beginning" (of creation.) See pages 2 & 3 of this second booklet.

This is the basis, the foundation, though (so far) it is clear that no Lucifer, or Satan, has been shown from the Bible to be a younger brother of the pre-mortal Jesus. But the key point lies in grasping the LDS doctrine of the pre-mortal Jesus being the (literal) firstborn spirit child of a Father in heaven who went on to father myriad other spirit children. The one known as Satan in the Bible, is believed to be the Lucifer of Isaiah 14:12-15.

No Bible text seems to me to be proposed to support the LDS belief that this Lucifer had a plan to save mankind, which his Father God rejected in favour of Jehovah's plan (who became the man, Jesus). However, Joseph Smith himself indicated his belief that Satan and Jesus were spirit brothers and sons of their Father God before the spirit of Jesus was given a body by Mary. In his *Book of Moses*, he has Satan and Jesus contending for the privilege of taking a body of flesh so as to become the redeemer, Jesus winning the contest. See *Pearl of Great Price*, by Joseph Smith, *Book of Moses* 4:1-4. Of course, that is not a Bible reference.

Comment: +1, decent answer, additional *biblical scriptures* might be 1 Peter 1:19-20, John 6:38, 40, and Rev 12:7-9, 11. I'll also mention that the LDS canon is not limited to the bible, so limiting answers to partial canon makes most answers incomplete no matter how well fleshed out with the restrictions, its still a partial view

Comment: @depperm  Yes, I'm sure various Bible texts are woven into this LDS doctrine - I was not out to give an exhaustive list! The point remains, however, that none of them actually show that "Jesus & Satan are spirit brothers who volunteered to be the Saviour of the world". The OP wants to know where, in the BIBLE this is stated. The straightforward LDS answer ought to be, "Nowhere", surely? The OP is not asking for an LDS explanation of the doctrine, simply whether the Bible makes that claim.

Comment: yes, but the question is limiting sources. Note meta question: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7465/22319

Comment: @depperm  Of necessity, certain Qs have to limit sources in answers if their Q is not to become a different Q. The Q asked here by the OP would become nonsense if opened up to sources other than the source sought for in the Q.

Comment: it wouldn't become nonsense as it seems scoped to lds, who have larger canon. It should go from partial answer to full answer by accepting scripture lds accept

Comment: @depperm  The scope requires whoever knows the answer to show from the Bible what the answer is. If the Bible states what is being asked about, anyone knowing the Bible well enough to says "It doesn't", can answer. Equally, if any LDS people know where their Bible says "It does; here..." then it would be very easy for them to give such an answer. It is not so much 'who' is being scoped here, as 'what' is being scoped. No further comments from me unless my answer is proven wrong by anyone; then I will admit I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

No where fully in the bible.

The quoted scripture (Job 38:7) is not the basis of the claim *Jesus and Satan are spirit brothers and they both volunteered to be the Savior of mankind*, it is the basis for *When the plan for our salvation was presented to us in the premortal spirit world, we were so happy that we shouted for joy*<sup>1</sup> as the linked article states.

As several comments note, the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints have more canon then the bible, which includes the Book of Mormon, Pearl of Great Price, and Doctrine and Covenants.<sup>2</sup> In addition to this they believe in revelation through modern apostles and prophets.<sup>3</sup> Restricting answers to only select books will only give an incomplete answer of a particular denominations view point.

The linked article includes many of the scriptures from the Pearl of Great Price (books Abraham and Moses) that support the belief in question.

<sub>1 https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-3-jesus-christ-our-chosen-leader-and-savior?lang=eng</sub>

<sub>2 [Historicity of LDS Scriptures](https://rsc.byu.edu/historicity-latter-day-saint-scriptures/latter-day-saint-concept-canon), related meta: [Should questions about particular denominations use the Scriptural Canon espoused by that particular those particular denominations?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7465/22319)</sub>

<sub>3 [Prophets](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/prophets?lang=eng)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for responding to my comments by answering.  I just wanted to add that the1st Article of Faith of the LDS declares belief in "the Bible to be the word of God as far as it is translated correctly", so a request for any statement in the Bible is acceptable. But the Q is just asking whether the Bible states that LDS doctrine. 'Scripture' may go beyond the Bible with some, but 'the Bible' clarifies which Scripture is sought. Your first reference gives an interpretation of a point in the Bible, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: @Anne its the [8th article](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/a-of-f/1?lang=eng&id=8#p8) that has that. It also states `We believe the Bible to be the word of God as far as it is translated correctly; we also believe the Book of Mormon to be the word of God.` restricting an lds question to just the book of Mormon would be equally restrictive to answers when querying lds beliefs. Not sure what you're basing the second half of your statement off of

Comment: Sorry - yes it's the 8th article. And I have corrected my answer to change 'basis' to 'support', as per your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the Bible in all its translations, in its current revisions and being removed from its sources over time might not be completely unambiguous on the subject, hence a need for revelation.

But we do indeed have the following statement in Scripture regarding Lucifer's fall:

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! (Isaiah 14:12).

The Hebrew word here means "morning star".

Jesus declares of Himself,

> I am the root and the offspring of David, and the bright and morning star."
> (Revelation 22:16)

At a baseline, many Christian denominations accept that Lucifer was once an angel. But the Bible itself further refers to Lucifer in his former state as the same type of being as Jesus Christ, specifically a "son", moreover one of the first. It is no more blasphemous to say that Lucifer was at least once an angel, than it is to say that a being created by God can fall from heaven, which the Scriptures plainly state that Lucifer did. But the Scriptures add to this by stating specifically that he was a son, and one of the first sons at that.
Who was Lucifer a son of? Lucifer was a son of God spiritually in the same way that Jehovah was, except that Jehovah is the Firstborn (Psalm 89:27, Isaiah 41:4, Col. 1:15). It follows logically that **if Lucifer was a son of the same Father as Jesus Christ, then the two were brothers**. I say *were* because in every necessary sense to distance from evil, God has disowned Lucifer/Satan (we know it is possible for Him to disown His other children too, so even though this would be the first such instance, it would not be the only one; see "perdition" in the Scriptures). One has to bend over backwards to ignore the fact that the Scriptures use the same term to identify the original lineage of Lucifer as that of Jesus Christ in premortality. It would seem that some form of unscriptural special pleading would be required to defy this conclusion.

Comment: The term in Revelation is ὁ ἀστὴρ ὁ λαμπρὸς ὁ πρωϊνός, *the star the bright the morning*, or in some manuscripts ὁ ἀστὴρ ὁ λαμπρὸς καὶ ὀρθρινός *the star the bright and morning*. The passage in Isaiah was written in Hebrew which the translators of the LXX understood as ὁ ἑωσφόρος ὁ πρωὶ ἀνατέλλων, *the daystar the morning rising*. Note the term ἑωσφόρος *daystar* is not used in the NT. There is no linguistic support for a claim Isaiah 14:12 and Revelation 22:16 are connected.